# Firebase API observeSingleEvent sometimes take 2-3 mins to hit completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are using Firebase (v5.15.0) in our Swift iOS application and we are trying to fetch user details like below.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { [weak self] (snapshot) in
            /*
My custom code
*/
}
```

Randomly the completion handler for `observeSingleEvent` takes 2-3 mins to hit. Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

**Background:**
I do not have any issues related to internet speed, as I have a decent speed connectivity. I tested this in both Cellular and Wi-Fi networks and I am able to face this issue in both ways.
My application database is a pretty large with around 5k users and around 500k items adding items in all the users.

Comment: Hi iam also using firebase dabase for chat module.This is no way to take 2-3 min, Please check in backgroud someother task is running

(Using for observe Online status)
class func observeChangeStatus(toID: String, completion: @escaping([TextMessageContent]) -> Swift.Void) {
        
        if let passengerChatID = passengerChatID() {
            fireBaseDataBaseRef.child("users").child(passengerChatID).child("conversations_list").child(toID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

Comment: This is a pretty vague question and the code in the question doesn't duplicate the issue is it takes .0037s in my App. You could have a firewall issue, slow internet, wireless router problem, something else in the code or quite possibly you're getting the data but the code is not responding in the way you expect (i.e. a coding error). We would need a lot more testing and datapoints to even attempt an answer. Did you try it on a different computer? Try it outside your network? Try it on a different device or simulator? If you can update your question we can take a look.

Comment: That's definitely longer than usual. The code you shared looks fine, so can't be the cause of it. Aside from the things Sathish Jay mentioned, you might want to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_) to see what the Firebase client is trying under the hood.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the reply. I have tested and tried all the cases and scenarios mentioned by Jay and Sathish before posting this question. I just wanted to understand if there any issues with that particular Firebase API and if there are any optimization suggestions I need to add while using this API. As I mentioned in the question, this issue is not happening all the time. It happens once in 10 times or more. Let me try debugging my self.